# Elasticsearch - 7.17 - Exception on Transport layer

Tags: elasticsearch, centos7

I'm trying to start elasticsearch 7.17 on Centos 7 but receiving lot of warnings when its running. Is there any way to get rid of this warning ?. the elasticsearch is running on a single node

exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9300, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:45464, profile=default}], closing connection
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [6.5.4] minimal compatible version is: [6.8.0]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundDecoder.ensureVersionCompatibility(InboundDecoder.java:214) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.8.jar:7.17.8]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundDecoder.readHeader(InboundDecoder.java:181) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.8.jar:7.17.8]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundDecoder.internalDecode(InboundDecoder.java:65) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.8.jar:7.17.8]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundDecoder.decode(InboundDecoder.java:43) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.8.jar:7.17.8]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundPipeline.doHandleBytes(InboundPipeline.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.8.jar:7.17.8]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.InboundPipeline.handleBytes(InboundPipeline.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.8.jar:7.17.8]

I tried to start the elasticsearch but got lot of warnings on the deprecation and is it possible to start it without the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Received message from unsupported version: [6.5.4] minimal compatible version is: [6.8.0]

The problem is that your client is running with a 6.5.4 library and your server is 7.17.8 which is compatible up to 6.8, i.e. a major version is compatible with the latest minor version of the previous major version, but not below. So you should upgrade your client library to at least 6.8, preferably 7.17.8.